# CFN yml SNS subscription not taking filterPolicyScope into consideration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CFN stack where I am defining a new SQS which will subscribe to a SNS with a filter policy. I am defining the filterpolicy and filterPolicyScope as follows -

```
- name: EventMessageSNSSubscription
  topicArn: { "Fn::FindInMap": [ 'EventMessageTopicMap', Ref: 'AWS::Region', Ref: 'Stage' ] }
  region: { Ref: 'AWS::Region' }
  protocol: sqs
  endpoint: { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "EventMessageQueue", "Arn" ] }
  filterPolicyScope: 'MessageBody'
  filterPolicy: '{"groupType": ["ALPHA"],"programAttributes":{"offerings": ["BETA"],"type": ["GAMMA"]}}'
```

While deploying my changes I am getting the following error while creating this subscription -

```
Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Filter policy scope MessageAttributes does not support nested filter policy (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 76ba3243-ca5c-5be8-9bfc-6fe457e520ed; Proxy: null)
```

Is there something syntactically wrong with how I am defining the filterScopePolicy? I am referring to this [documentation from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html#aws-resource-sns-subscription--examples) and [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/). I am guessing since MessageAttributes is default filterScopePolicy the policy I mention is being ignored somehow due to syntax error?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - do you have a minimal example you can share please?

Comment: This is part of very big stack where I am adding a SQS to already established stack. The previous SQS here don’t have a filter policy attached to it so I have no point of reference. Maybe this is because of Jinja or some older version of aws stacks or something? I have no idea because this is my first time working with cfn with yml files.

Comment: Can we see a few lines above and below the above block please?

Comment: That's not cloudformation.  Looks like data you are cooking into a cloudformation template yourself?  What does the actual cloudformation look like?  Sounds to me like it's not picking up the correct `FilterPolicyScope`.

Comment: Yeah sorry yes we are cooking data into the cloudformation template. Its not picking up `FilterPolicyScope` in the cloudformation and taking the default value as we mention filterPolicyScope in our data.

Comment: Updated the jinja template to look for the variable in data and it worked. `{% if snsSubscription.filterPolicyScope %}
      FilterPolicyScope: {{ snsSubscription.filterPolicyScope }}
    {% endif %}`